# Python - Applying new functions to builtin classes

Tags: python, built-in

I'm using Python 2.6.6 and I want to know if I can apply new functions to builtin classes and types **without subclassing it**, for example:

```
t1 = (20,20)
t2 = (40,30)
print t2 - t1 #gives me (20,10)
print t2 + t1 #gives me (60,50)
```

To do this I need to add __sub__ and __add__ functions to tuple class.
Is it possible?

Comment: did you want to add and sub values?

Comment: If you want to implement the minus sign you need to implement __sub__ and __add__ for plus so I do.. It was just an example but is there any problem with this?

Comment: what's your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't strictly have to subclass, you can make a class and pass in a tuple making sure you have a `__getitem__` method defined also:

```
class Tuple(object):
    def __init__(self, t):
        self.t = t

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.t[item]

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self[0] + other[0], self[1]+other[1]

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self[0] - other[0], self[1] - other[1]


t1 = MyTuple((20,20))
t2 = MyTuple((40,30))

print(t2 - t1)
print(t2 + t1)
```

You cannot change any types defined in  C extension modules as they are **immutable**, if you want different behaviour you need to either subclass or create a custom class and pass in the type as above.